# Algolia filter by sub key value

Tags: search, algolia

I have data like where one set is:

```
{
  "creatorUsername": "mbalex99",
  "description": "For Hikers and All the Lovers Alike!",
  "imageUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/edenmessenger/uploads/28C03B77-E3E9-4D33-A433-6522C0480C16.jpg",
  "isPrivate": true,
  "name": "Nature Lovers ",
  "roomId": "-KILq0nBN8wHQuEjMYRF",
  "usernames": {
    "bannon": true,
    "loveless": true,
    "mbalex99": true,
    "terra": true
  },
  "objectID": "-KILq0nBN8wHQuEjMYRF"
}
```

I can't seem to find `usernames` where a key equals `mbalex99`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed not possible with Algolia. You can only filter by value.
However, you can definitely add an array containing the keys of your object and filter by this attribute:

```coffee
"usernames": {
  "bannon": true,
  "loveless": true,
  "mbalex99": true,
  "terra": true
},
"usernameList": ["bannon", "loveless", "mbalex99", "terra"]
// ...
```

and

```coffee
// At query time:
{ "facetFilters": "usernameList:mbalex99" }
```